# JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException with React Native Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, react-native

Recently we've integrated react native into our app with just simple text view. We're getting this crash on all kind of devices.

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.bridge.JSApplicationIllegalArgumentException: Error while updating property 'flex' in shadow node of type: RCTView
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:109)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:148)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:52)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode.updateProperties(ReactShadowNode.java:222)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:177)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:222)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:318)
       at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode.setFlex argument 1 has type float, got java.lang.String
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagersPropertyCache$PropSetter.updateShadowNodeProp(ViewManagersPropertyCache.java:99)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater$FallbackShadowNodeSetter.setProperty(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:148)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.updateProps(ViewManagerPropertyUpdater.java:52)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.ReactShadowNode.updateProperties(ReactShadowNode.java:222)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIImplementation.createView(UIImplementation.java:177)
       at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerModule.createView(UIManagerModule.java:222)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.BaseJavaModule$JavaMethod.invoke(BaseJavaModule.java:318)
       at com.facebook.react.cxxbridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:158)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:31)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:196)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

We show simple text with React Native

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class HelloWorld extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>React Native is running</Text>
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('8fit', () => HelloWorld);
```

We use React Native `0.35.0-rc.0` but we've been getting same crash also with stable release `0.33.1`.

You can find full crash report here.
https://gist.github.com/sealskej/1e2398ef1cd9dda2d1b2630348fa612a

Any help leading to fixing issue would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hey, are you able reproduce the issue with the above code? I tried the same code, but didn't get the crash.

Comment: Check in your react-native codebase if you are using flex keyword, and the value is a string. Error clearly specifies a string value is passed instead of float type.

Comment: You said `integrate`, so it's not a pure React Native project, right? The code looks good, it might be a setup error. Check your setup part, you may find something.

Comment: @Jickson I'm not able to reproduce the issue. I just see it happening randomly for some users.

Comment: @Jickson No, we're not using the flex keyword in js file at all.

Comment: @Swordsman Yes, we've added React Native to existing project. It works fine on my emulator and all our test devices, so I'm not sure it's setup error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why this doesn't work but perhaps a solution would be to wrap it in a `View` and set the value of `flex` there. For example:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
         <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>React Native is running</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The version of react in package.json file being used may be different than the sdk version that is being used in apk.

This can give IllegalArgumentException everytime.

Comment: I use `maven { url "$rootDir/node_modules/react-native/android" }` and `compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"`, which should ensure react native versions are the same after `npm install`, no?